# Suggestions for a Flipview with Pages inside (Windows 8.1 app)

Tags: windows-store-apps, focus, windows-8.1, flipview

I'm trying to create an app which shows a different page on swiping left or right.
I'm using the flipview control and loading it with Page class objects.

It works well, but when I select a textbox inside, the control recieving the focus is the flipview instead of the textbox, and then the keyboard covers it.

My question is, how I should implement his UI?

The actual structure is something like (this is not real code, but the simpliest way to show the structure)

```
<Page>
    <FlipView> <---- This gets the focus instead of the textbox

            <SetupPage>
                <TextBox1 /> <--- This textbox is clicked and shows the keyboard
            </SetupPage>

            <AnalyzePage>
                <TextBox2 />
            </AnalyzePage>

    </Flipview>
</Page>
```

I've tried using FlipViewItem around the pages, and also trying to override the focus logic of the flipview. I haven't suceeded in any case.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you put your pages (SetupPage, AnalyzePage etc) into a FlipViewItem? I used a FlipView with ListViews each within a FlipViewItem. And then inside my ListView there are TextBoxes inside a stackpanel. My textboxes behave normally as expected.